# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \left[\frac{n}{i(i+1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{i(i+1)} (n(H_{n-2} - H_{n-i-1}) - (i-1))) \right] =(n-1)^2$?

Tags: calculus, summation, harmonic-numbers

Apparently the following expression
$$
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \Bigg[\frac{n}{i(i+1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{i(i+1)} (n(H_{n-2} - H_{n-i-1})  - (i-1)))   \Bigg] \\
$$

simplifies to $(n-1)^2$, where $H_i$ is the i-th harmonic number.

I tried to simplify but I'm not seeing the simplification
\begin{align}
    \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \Bigg[\frac{n}{i(i+1)} + \frac{n(n-1)}{i(i+1)} (n(H_{n-2} - H_{n-i-1})  - (i-1)))   \Bigg] \\
    =    n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i(i+1)}\Bigg[1 + (n-1) (n(H_{n-2} - H_{n-i-1})  - (i-1)))   \Bigg]
\end{align}
It's not obvious to me how I can further simplify, especially with the harmonic terms.

In addition, what kind of series is $\sum_i \frac{1}{i(i+1)}$?

I have a little Python script below in case anyone wants to see that the 2 expressions are equal:

````
def solution(n):
  ans = 0
  for i in range(1, n):
    sum1 = 0

    for r in range(n-i, n-1):
      sum1 += 1/r

    sum1 *= n
    sum1 -= i-1
    sum1 *= n*(n-1)/i/(i+1);

    ans += sum1 + n/i/(i+1)

  return ans


for n in range(100,1000):
  print(solution(n) - (n-1)**2)
```
````

Comment: Not sure if I made a mistake or not. But in my notes it does not hold for $n=3$. I got the sum equal to -16.

Comment: @Mihail Apologies. There's an extraneous set of parenthesis on the last harmonic number.

Comment: @ dd22205 +1 Nice problem. But where did you get this complicated expression from?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I was solving the problem “given n balls, all with unique colors, you draw 2 balls at random and for each pair you change the first balls color to the second. Then you put the balls back into the container. What is the expected number of draws to get all balls to be one color” and the approach I took resulted in the above expression.

Comment: @ dd22205 Interesting combinatorical problem. Did you post it somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got $-(n-1)^2$ and by calculating the first few cases, it seems to be the correct answer. I will assume that $n\geq 2$ and $H_0=0$. First note that
$$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{i(i + 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\left[ {\frac{1}{i} - \frac{1}{{i + 1}}} \right]}  = 1 - \frac{1}{n}.
$$
We can decompose the sum into
\begin{align*}
& n\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{i(i + 1)}}}  + n^2 (n - 1)H_{n - 2} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{i(i + 1)}}}  - n^2 (n - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i(i + 1)}}} \\ &\quad - n(n - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{i}} 
\\ &
 = n - 1 + n(n - 1)^2 H_{n - 2}  - n^2 (n - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i(i + 1)}}}  - n(n - 1)H_{n - 1} 
\\ &
 = n - 1 + n(n - 1)^2 H_{n - 2}  - n^2 (n - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i(i + 1)}}}  - n(n - 1)\left( {H_{n - 2}  + \frac{1}{{n - 1}}} \right)
\\ &
 =  - 1 + n(n - 1)(n - 2)H_{n - 2}  - n^2 (n - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i(i + 1)}}} .
\end{align*}
Now
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i(i + 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i(i + 1)}}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} {\left[ {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{i} - \frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i + 1}}} \right]} \\ & = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} {\left[ {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{i} - \frac{{H_{n - i - 2}  + \frac{1}{{n - i - 1}}}}{{i + 1}}} \right]} 
\\ &
 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} {\left[ {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{i} - \frac{{H_{n - i - 2} }}{{i + 1}}} \right]}  + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} {\frac{1}{{(n - i - 1)(i + 1)}}} \\ & = H_{n - 2}  + \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 2} {\left[ {\frac{1}{{n - i - 1}} + \frac{1}{{i + 1}}} \right]} 
\\ &
 = H_{n - 2}  + \frac{1}{n}\left( {H_{n - 1}  - 1 + H_{n - 2} } \right).
\end{align*}
Therefore, the original sum is
$$
 - 1 + n(n - 1)(n - 2)H_{n - 2}  - n^2 (n - 1)H_{n - 2}  + n(n - 1)\left( {H_{n - 1}  - 1 + H_{n - 2} } \right) \\ =  - n^2  + 2n - 1 =  - (n - 1)^2 .
$$

Comment: Ugh you're right. I had another typo in my OP. It should have been $-(i-1)$ rather than $-i-1$. I think flips the sign.

Comment: Also, in the line before "Now", if you plug in $n=1$, you get $-1$. But that seems to be a contradiction?

Comment: You get $0$ because $H_0=H_{-1}=0$.

Comment: Hmm, are you referring to the line $- 1 + n(n - 1)(n - 2)H_{n - 2}  - n^2 (n - 1)\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{{H_{n - i - 1} }}{{i(i + 1)}}}$? For $n=1$ doesn't this give $-1 + 0 - 0$?

Comment: @dd22205 Ok, I see. The line before that work only if $n$ is at least $2$. Of course, the case $n=1$ can be checked easily since an empty sum is $0$. So I put this assumption to the beginning of the derivation.

Comment: Sorry, I get +(n-1)^2

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze  That is because the question was modified since I gave my answer.

Comment: @ Gary Ok. Just one little flaw: $H_{-1}$ is not zero as you have stated but $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but an observation which is too long for a comment.

I have tried to simplify the problem checking the steps with Mathematica - and found a strange behaviour.

If we replace the difference of the harmonic numbers for $n\ge 2$ and $1 \le i \le n-1$ by

$$n \left(H_{n-2}-H_{n-i-1}\right) \to \sum _{m=0}^{i-2} \frac{n}{-m+n-2}\tag{1}$$

then the summand of the sum in question becomes

$$B(n,i)=\frac{n}{i (i+1)}+\frac{n (n-1)}{i (i+1)} \left(\sum _{m=0}^{i-2} \frac{n}{-m+n-2}-(i-1)\right)\tag{2}$$

Doing now the sum over $i$ for given $n=5$, for example, gives on the one hand

$$\sum _{i=1}^{n-1} B(n,i)=(n^2-n)|_{n\to 5}=20\tag{3} $$

and on the other hand

$$\sum _{i=1}^{5-1} B(5,i)=16\tag{4} $$

Because we know that the result of the summation is (n-1)^2 the first (symbolic) result is wrong, and the second one is correct. Something with the generic sum runs off road. I just found a similar (maybe the same) problem here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221373/possible-bug-in-finite-sum-over-inverse-squares-sum-limits-i-1n-frac1x/221484?noredirect=1#comment563875_221484